# Cannot read property '0' of undefined - Angular 6 and Angular Material - mat-radio-group [(ngModel)] set dynamic variable inside *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 6 and Angular Angular Material, 
I have dynamic list of polls with list of options. I want to show selected option with two way data binding. as my list is dynamic i want to pass variable in [(ngModel)]. tried passing variable but no luck please suggest alternate solution 
error Cannot read property '0' of undefined

[stackblitz example code to reproduce issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-two-way-data-binding-with-dynamic-ngmodel)

Same code works when data loaded from local array [local data stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-two-way-data-binding-with-dyamic-name-static-data)

Comment: Where is `myselection`?

Comment: I am not able to access the link.

Comment: Try accessing again i have just made edits

Comment: Hi yurzui  i want myselection to be dynamic  value

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-two-way-data-binding-with-dyamic-name-static-data working example when  data is local but issue which json data  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template does not match your component. If you check the error using Firefox Dev Tools, you'll see: "_co.myselection is undefined". `myselection` is not defined anywhere in your component.

Comment: Hi Markus  i have this code working when data i local but when data loaded via http facing isssue. working code . :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-two-way-data-binding-with-dyamic-name-static-data

Comment: but that's not the same code. in your working example you refer to selectedAnswers in your template, and selectedAnswers exists in your component. in your non-working example, you refer to myselection in your template and myselection does NOT exist in your component

Comment: Yeh i missed that that was issue. Thanks